# Deny referrals from all domains except one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-referer

Is it possible to accept traffic from only one domain, ideally using a .htaccess file?
I want my site to only be accessible via a link on another site I have.

I know how to block one referring domain, but not all domains

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} otherdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

this is my full rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I think it is working, but none of the assets are getting loaded and I get a 500 error when I click on another link.

Comment: I assume that ` there is a copy-and-paste error?

Answer (score 5):

Make that something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !alloweddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

The first `RewriteCond` checks that the referrer is not empty.  The second checks that it doesn't contain the string `yourdomain.com`, and the third that it doesn't contain the string `alloweddomain.com`.  If all of these checks pass, the `RewriteRule` triggers and denies the request.

(Allowing empty referrers is generally a good idea, since browsers can generate them for various reasons, such as when:

- the user has bookmarked the link,
- the user entered the link manually into the address bar,
- the user reloaded the page,
- the browser is configured not to send cross-site referrer infromation, or
- a proxy between your site and the browser strips away the referrer information.)

Comment: many thanks for the quick reply, I am getting a 500 error for some reason.

Comment: Check you server logs to see what's causing the 500 error, then.

Comment: so it does work, but the page loads without my css and images

Comment: OK, obvious question: you have remembered to allow referrers from your _own_ domain too, right?

Comment: sorry, that was very stupid! working great now, thanks so much.

Comment: one strange thing, if a link to the site is in a email it is not blocked.

Comment: Links from e-mail messages (and other things that are not websites) are another situation where browsers typically won't send any referrer information for technical and privacy reasons.

Comment: ok thank you! I would love to block empty referrers as well, but I think it would stop too many genuine requests.