# .htaccess redirect referrer on specific URL visit

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, referrer

I have understood the basics of redirecting a refferer through .htaccess but the only things i could manage to do with the .htaccess file was to either deny the entry of the whole folder or of a file but i never understood how to set up a redirection rule on a custom index page for example

What im trying to go for:

I want only 1 specific referrer to be able to visit this site "http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=Custom&pageID=7"

Everyone else that is not the specified referer should get redirected to another page.

I tried numerous php scripts for referrer detection but none of them seemed to work for me unfortunately

I would be very thankful for a solution :)

EDIT: Something like this ofcourse this doesn't work unfortunately

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.refferersite\.org/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/index.php?page=Custom&pageID=7 http://newsite.com/index.php [L]"
```

Comment: Do you want to allow access from only one IP address?

Comment: Either that or from a certain page doesn't really matter actually. I just want people to visit that site from the specific referrer

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give a simple example, things become a little more complicated if you're taking in form variables or something.  But for your .htaccess you would want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} referringsite\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* index.php?page=Custom&pageID=7 [L,QSA]
```

The rewrite condition must be true in order to trigger the rewrite.  At which point the `.*` tells it to rewrite the entire query to `index.php?page=...`.

The `L` will make it stop processing other rules (so if you have any, they don't rewrite this rewrite).

The `qsa` will maintain any query parameters.  So if they are also passing in something like `?campaign=my_ad_campaign`, it gets attached to the end of your index page.

Hope this helps!

--Update--
I think you want this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !referringsite\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule index.php?page=Custom&pageID=7 index.php [L]
```

Do not include the http in the referring site.

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't let me visit the page anymore at all :S And where exactly do i get redirected another site here?

Comment: I apologize, but I'm not really sure how this would block it.  Could you please copy and paste your entire .htaccess here? (XXX'ing the domain name if you'd like)

Comment: Never mind what i said i can visit the site now but i think you have missunderstood me. I don't want people from "referringsite.com" to be directed to "index.php?page=Custom&pageID=7" bur rather people from "referringsite.com" to be the only 1 that are possible to visit the customID=7 page.

Maybe this will show a little better what i am going thru unfortunately this code ofcourse doesn't work:

EDIT: Cant figure out how to put code in here ill put it on my first post instead above

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you're going for.
I think if you change
`RewriteRule ^/index.php?page=Custom&pageID=8 http://newsite.com/index.php [L]`
to
`RewriteRule ^/index.php?page=Custom&pageID=8 index.php [L]`
It might do what you want?

Comment: Exactly like the version i have provided it doesn't do anything it doesn't seem to recognize the "^/indexphp?..." maybe bad reggex formating?

Answer (score 0):

can u try this?:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !alloweddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

The first RewriteCond checks that the referrer is not empty. The second checks that it doesn't contain the string yourdomain.com, and the third that it doesn't contain the string alloweddomain.com. If all of these checks pass, the RewriteRule triggers and denies the request.

[Deny referrals from all domains except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572604/deny-referrals-from-all-domains-except-one)