# htaccess allow access from specific domains

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website domain1.com and all articles include download links to domain2.com like this
http://domain2.com/file1.rar
http://domain2.com/file2.rar
.....
I want only user who is reading article on domain1.com can download above files
Even cannot download if use direct link (without referral from domain1.com)

I try as this guide but fail
[Deny referrals from all domains except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572604/deny-referrals-from-all-domains-except-one)

Answer (score 0):

You need to place this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` of `domain2.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule \.rar$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Totally agree. I should have mentioned that `%{HTTP_REFERER}` can be esily manipulated.